# Better approach at preserving "audit" logs but periodically curating "debug" logs?

Tags: elasticsearch

When working with an EFK stack with separate indices for Debug logs vs. Audit logs, is there a **safer/cleaner practice** than running [curator](https://github.com/elastic/curator) to periodically trim my Debug logs (which will bloat) while preserving sensitive audit logs for long (indefinite) durations of time?

In other words, I'm considering running curator on a cron job and periodically trimming out older debug traces by filtering my time-based indices using a pre-arranged naming convention to differentiate between *audit* and *debug*.

The alternatives I can see are two separate elasticsearch clusters (one for Audit, one for Debug) which feels a bit too heavy to preserve debug logs temporarily for a few days.

Comment: The alternative is as you've started. Cron is a perfectly fine approach to clearing out the debug logs.

Comment: True but performing "delete" operations to temporary/throwaway indices that are alongside some very sensitive (cannot ever be deleted) indices feels unsafe. A typo in your curator filter and you could be nuking your audit data.

Comment: Yes, agreed. The alternative is what you already mentioned and would be my preference, but if it's too heavy for you, cron is a perfectly fine approach. Seems like you are already aware of the pros and cons for each